# what is difference between "Compliment" and "Complement"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I am confused about these two words.
For example
1) Love is the complement of law.
2)He complimented me.
what is difference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complement = add to something in a way that enhances or improves

> that dress complements you

compliment = admire and praise someone for something

> you look healthy

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825045206/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/complement-or-compliment)